# How do I install pgadmin3 using brew cask?

Tags: homebrew

If I try running `brew cask install pgadmin3`, as suggested on an unknown website http://macappstore.org/pgadmin3/ I get "Cask 'pgadmin3' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.", an error message that doesn't get any hits on this stack exchange.

```
$ brew cask install pgadmin3
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/cask).
No changes to formulae.

Error: Cask 'pgadmin3' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.
```

Another user encountered the same problem, and thought that it was necessary to install pgadmin4 instead. How do I install pgadmin3 with homebrew?

Answer (score 5):

It's necessary to turn on cask-versions, a project mentioned at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions

```
$ brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/cask).

==> Tapping homebrew/cask-versions
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 228, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (228/228), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (217/217), done.
remote: Total 228 (delta 16), reused 51 (delta 10), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (228/228), 92.05 KiB | 4.84 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (16/16), done.
Tapped 208 casks (248 files, 350.3KB).


$ brew cask install pgadmin3
==> Satisfying dependencies
==> Downloading https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin3/v1.22.2/osx/pgadmin3-1.22.2.dmg
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Verifying SHA-256 checksum for Cask 'pgadmin3'.
==> Installing Cask pgadmin3
==> Moving App 'pgAdmin3.app' to '/Applications/pgAdmin3.app'.
  pgadmin3 was successfully installed!
```

Also, when the application is first opened, a '“pgAdmin3” can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer.' message will be encountered, which can be fixed by opening the application from the application folder, as documented at [The app can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/master/doc/faq/the_app_cant_be_opened.md)

Comment: I had to do `brew install --cask pgadmin3` after running `brew tap homebrew/cask-versions` .